# при запуске функции, появляется незапланированный div

Tags: javascript

```
<style type="text/css">
   html{background:#fff;cursor:default;font:16px calibri, sans-serif;}
   div{padding:20px;border:5px solid #69c;}
   p{margin:0;padding:30px;background:#ccf;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="a">
   <p id="b" onclick="alert('Hello!')">Кликнуть здесь</p>
</div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var x = document.getElementById('b');
</script>
```

После запуска скрипта, на html-странице появляется непонятный div:

```
<div id="SL_balloon_obj" alt="0" style="display: block;"><div id="SL_button" class="SL_ImTranslatorLogo" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/imtranslator-s.png&quot;); display: none;"></div><div id="SL_shadow_translation_result2" style="display: none;"></div><div id="SL_shadow_translator" style="display: none;"><div id="SL_planshet" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/bg2.png&quot;) rgb(244, 245, 245);"><div id="SL_arrow_up" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/up.png&quot;);"></div><div id="SL_providers"><div class="SL_BL_LABLE_ON" title="Google" id="SL_P0">G</div><div class="SL_BL_LABLE_ON" title="Microsoft" id="SL_P1">M</div><div class="SL_BL_LABLE_ON" title="Translator" id="SL_P2">T</div></div><div id="SL_alert_bbl"><div id="SLHKclose" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/delete.png&quot;);"></div><div id="SL_alert_cont"></div></div><div id="SL_TB"><div id="SL_bubblelogo" class="SL_ImTranslatorLogo" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/imtranslator-s.png&quot;);"></div><table id="SL_tables" cellspacing="1"><tr><td class="SL_td" width="10%" align="right"><input id="SL_locer" type="checkbox" title="Зафиксировать язык"></td><td class="SL_td" width="20%" align="left"><select id="SL_lng_from"><option value="auto">Определить язык</option><option value="az">Азербайджанский</option><option value="sq">Албанский</option><option value="en">Английский</option><option value="ar">Арабский</option><option value="hy">Армянский</option><option value="af">Африкаанс</option><option value="eu">Баскский</option><option value="be">Белорусский</option><option value="bn">Бенгальский</option><option value="my">Бирманский</option><option value="bg">Болгарский</option><option value="bs">Боснийский</option><option value="cy">Валлийский</option><option value="hu">Венгерский</option><option value="vi">Вьетнамский</option><option value="gl">Галисийский</option><option value="el">Греческий</option><option value="ka">Грузинский</option><option value="gu">Гуджарати</option><option value="da">Датский</option><option value="zu">Зулу</option><option value="iw">Иврит</option><option value="ig">Игбо</option><option value="yi">Идиш</option><option value="id">Индонезийский</option><option value="ga">Ирландский</option><option value="is">Исландский</option><option value="es">Испанский</option><option value="it">Итальянский</option><option value="yo">Йоруба</option><option value="kk">Казахский</option><option value="kn">Каннада</option><option value="ca">Каталанский</option><option value="zh-CN">Китайский (Трад)</option><option value="zh-TW">Китайский (Упр)</option><option value="ko">Корейский</option><option value="ht">Креольский (Гаити)</option><option value="km">Кхмерский</option><option value="lo">Лаосский</option><option value="la">Латинский</option><option value="lv">Латышский</option><option value="lt">Литовский</option><option value="mk">Македонский</option><option value="mg">Малагасийский</option><option value="ms">Малайский</option><option value="ml">Малайялам</option><option value="mt">Мальтийский</option><option value="mi">Маори</option><option value="mr">Маратхи</option><option value="mn">Монгольский</option><option value="de">Немецкий</option><option value="ne">Непали</option><option value="nl">Нидерландский</option><option value="no">Норвежский</option><option value="pa">Панджаби</option><option value="fa">Персидский</option><option value="pl">Польский</option><option value="pt">Португальский</option><option value="ro">Румынский</option><option value="ru">Русский</option><option value="ceb">Себуанский</option><option value="sr">Сербский</option><option value="st">Сесото</option><option value="si">Сингальский</option><option value="sk">Словацкий</option><option value="sl">Словенский</option><option value="so">Сомали</option><option value="sw">Суахили</option><option value="su">Суданский</option><option value="tl">Тагальский</option><option value="tg">Таджикский</option><option value="th">Тайский</option><option value="ta">Тамильский</option><option value="te">Телугу</option><option value="tr">Турецкий</option><option value="uz">Узбекский</option><option value="uk">Украинский</option><option value="ur">Урду</option><option value="fi">Финский</option><option value="fr">Французский</option><option value="ha">Хауса</option><option value="hi">Хинди</option><option value="hmn">Хмонг</option><option value="hr">Хорватский</option><option value="ny">Чева</option><option value="cs">Чешский</option><option value="sv">Шведский</option><option value="eo">Эсперанто</option><option value="et">Эстонский</option><option value="jw">Яванский</option><option value="ja">Японский</option></select></td><td class="SL_td" width="3" align="center"><div id="SL_switch_b" title="Перевернуть языки" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/switchb.png&quot;);"></div></td><td class="SL_td" width="20%" align="left"><select id="SL_lng_to"><option value="az">Азербайджанский</option><option value="sq">Албанский</option><option value="en">Английский</option><option value="ar">Арабский</option><option value="hy">Армянский</option><option value="af">Африкаанс</option><option value="eu">Баскский</option><option value="be">Белорусский</option><option value="bn">Бенгальский</option><option value="my">Бирманский</option><option value="bg">Болгарский</option><option value="bs">Боснийский</option><option value="cy">Валлийский</option><option value="hu">Венгерский</option><option value="vi">Вьетнамский</option><option value="gl">Галисийский</option><option value="el">Греческий</option><option value="ka">Грузинский</option><option value="gu">Гуджарати</option><option value="da">Датский</option><option value="zu">Зулу</option><option value="iw">Иврит</option><option value="ig">Игбо</option><option value="yi">Идиш</option><option value="id">Индонезийский</option><option value="ga">Ирландский</option><option value="is">Исландский</option><option value="es">Испанский</option><option value="it">Итальянский</option><option value="yo">Йоруба</option><option value="kk">Казахский</option><option value="kn">Каннада</option><option value="ca">Каталанский</option><option value="zh-CN">Китайский (Трад)</option><option value="zh-TW">Китайский (Упр)</option><option value="ko">Корейский</option><option value="ht">Креольский (Гаити)</option><option value="km">Кхмерский</option><option value="lo">Лаосский</option><option value="la">Латинский</option><option value="lv">Латышский</option><option value="lt">Литовский</option><option value="mk">Македонский</option><option value="mg">Малагасийский</option><option value="ms">Малайский</option><option value="ml">Малайялам</option><option value="mt">Мальтийский</option><option value="mi">Маори</option><option value="mr">Маратхи</option><option value="mn">Монгольский</option><option value="de">Немецкий</option><option value="ne">Непали</option><option value="nl">Нидерландский</option><option value="no">Норвежский</option><option value="pa">Панджаби</option><option value="fa">Персидский</option><option value="pl">Польский</option><option value="pt">Португальский</option><option value="ro">Румынский</option><option selected="selected" value="ru">Русский</option><option value="ceb">Себуанский</option><option value="sr">Сербский</option><option value="st">Сесото</option><option value="si">Сингальский</option><option value="sk">Словацкий</option><option value="sl">Словенский</option><option value="so">Сомали</option><option value="sw">Суахили</option><option value="su">Суданский</option><option value="tl">Тагальский</option><option value="tg">Таджикский</option><option value="th">Тайский</option><option value="ta">Тамильский</option><option value="te">Телугу</option><option value="tr">Турецкий</option><option value="uz">Узбекский</option><option value="uk">Украинский</option><option value="ur">Урду</option><option value="fi">Финский</option><option value="fr">Французский</option><option value="ha">Хауса</option><option value="hi">Хинди</option><option value="hmn">Хмонг</option><option value="hr">Хорватский</option><option value="ny">Чева</option><option value="cs">Чешский</option><option value="sv">Шведский</option><option value="eo">Эсперанто</option><option value="et">Эстонский</option><option value="jw">Яванский</option><option value="ja">Японский</option></select></td><td class="SL_td" width="21%" align="center"> </td><td class="SL_td" width="6%" align="center"><div id="SL_TTS_voice" title="Прослушать" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/tts-voice.png&quot;);"></div></td><td class="SL_td" width="6%" align="center"><div id="SL_copy" title="Скопировать" class="SL_copy" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/copy_hand.png&quot;);"></div></td><td class="SL_td" width="6%" align="center"><div id="SL_bbl_font_patch"></div><div id="SL_bbl_font" title="Размер шрифта" class="SL_bbl_font" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/font-off.png&quot;);"></div></td><td class="SL_td" width="6%" align="center"><div id="SL_TH" title="История переводов" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/history.png&quot;);"></div></td><td class="SL_td" width="10%"> </td><td class="SL_td" width="8%" align="right"><div id="SL_pin" title="Закрепить всплывающее окно" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/pin-on.png&quot;);"></div></td></tr></table></div></div><div id="SL_shadow_translation_result" style="visibility: visible;"></div><div id="SL_loading" class="SL_loading" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/loading.gif&quot;);"></div><div id="SL_player2" style="display: none; height: 0px; width: 0px;"></div><div id="SL_alert100" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/bg2.png&quot;); display: none;">Звуковая функция ограничена 100 символами</div><div id="SL_Balloon_options" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/bg3.png&quot;) rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div id="SL_arrow_down" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/down.png&quot;);"></div><table width="100%"><tr><td width="18%" align="left" height="16"><div id="SL_bbl_donate" title="Сделать пожертвование" style="background: url(&quot;chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/img/util/donate2.png&quot;);"></div></td><td width="68%" align="center"><a href="chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/html/options/options.html?bbl" target="_blank" class="SL_options" title="Показать настройки">Настройки</a> : <a href="chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/html/options/options.html?hist" target="_blank" class="SL_options" title="История переводов">История</a> : <a href="http://about.imtranslator.net/tutorials/presentations/imtranslator-for-chrome/chrome-bubble-translator/" target="_blank" class="SL_options" title="Справка ImTranslator">Справка</a> : <a href="chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh/content/html/options/options.html?feed" target="_blank" class="SL_options" title="Обратная связь">Обратная связь</a></td><td width="15%" align="right"><span id="SL_Balloon_Close" title="Закрыть">Закрыть</span></td></tr></table></div></div></div>
```

Более того, он - div - визуально отрисовывается на странице, что совершенно не нужно. Предполагаю, что как-то связано с настройками Chome. Прошу помочь разобраться.

Comment: Дело в расширении для браузера chrome-extension://noaijdpnepcgjemiklgfkcfbkokogabh

Answer (score 2):

разобрался: это приложение, которое работает в браузере - ImTranslator. Отключил его и все отлично

Answer (score 0):

Аналогичная проблема:

SLG_balloon_obj

SLG_shadow_translator

SLG_shadow_translation_result

SLG_Balloon_options

и т.д.

Создаётся новый элемент при включенном расширении ГуглПереводчик.

[image: Гигантский новый элемент]

Comment: это разве ответ на вопрос?

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вы можете задать их нажав кнопку «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Дополнительно вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/776215)